# casperjs command not found

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I installed phantomjs on my mac

```
 phantomjs --version
1.9.2
```

Following the instructions on the casper installation page, I did this

```
$ git clone git://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
$ cd casperjs
$ ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

However, i'm getting command not found when I run `casperjs`. I also installed it via homebrew and got the same result.

Any suggestions?

Update

this is what I get when I type $PATH

```
-bash: /Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/me/downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.4.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin: No such file or directory
```

inside

`usr/local/bin`, there is (among other things)  `phantomjs` and `casperjs`. I can run phantomjs --version from anywhere and get the version number. `casperjs` doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely due to the symbolic link not being created.

Try running the command directly: `/usr/local/bin/casperjs --version`

If this results in another `Command not found` error, then you should try running

```
sudo ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

to make sure that you actually create the link in the `/usr/local/bin` directory

However, if it does exist, you should check to make sure that the link is pointing to the correct directory by running

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you got the ln command line parameters switched: first one is the target, second is the link.

Comment: That's not what it says on the casper installation page. Anyways, I  tried it the way you suggested, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install casperjs using npm

```
npm install casperjs
```

Then you can run it using:

```
node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs selftest
```